# Distinguishing quadratic residues of a number

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, quadratic-residues

Say we have a prime $p$, and its primitive root modulus $g$. Now if we have a number $x \equiv g^{2a}$ mod $p$ for $0 \le a \le p-1$, then its two quadratic residues $r_1 \equiv g^a$ mod $p$ and $r_2 \equiv g^{a+\frac{p-1}{2}}$ mod $p$ can be obtained using the Tonelli-Shanks algorithm.

As far as I understand, the algorithm can return either of the solution pairs $(r_1,r_2)$ or $(r_2,r_1)$. My question is that whether there's a way to know from the obtained roots, which one is precisely $g^a$ and which one is not?

Comment: Which ones of $g$ and $a$ do you know?

Comment: We know $p,g,x,$ and both roots.

Comment: I suspect an efficient algorithm for this would give rise to an efficient algorithm to calculate discrete logarithms.

Comment: @AnginaSeng Yes, that is true.

Comment: I wonder if you should title this Distinguishing rather than Differentiating, since differentiating has different connotations in mathematics

Comment: @J.W.T I almost made the same edit myself for the same reason (there is alos an [*arithmetic* derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_derivative))

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Thanks! I too thought it is misleading but a better word didn't strike my mind at that time.